# Call a whole string of arguments with subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Say I want to do: `subprocess.call(['whatever.exe',v])` where v is a string representing all the arguments to pass to `whatever.exe`. Is there a way to do this without breaking apart each argument individually?

Comment: What do you want to happen when arguments contain spaces? Quotes? Globs? (The value of passing an explicit list is that it's... well... *explicit*; all the expansion and splitting has been done ahead-of-time and under your control).

Comment: It's my code all the way down, it won't.

Comment: That's not always a sure thing, even when it *is* your own code. The biggest data loss issue I've personally witnessed was caused by a new program (which used a Python module with a bug where it was careless with a pointer) written in-house by our own people generating filenames with whitespace and globs (and other random content from memory) in a directory that "couldn't ever" include anything but names composed purely of hex digits. Script tries to delete that one file -> script deletes all our backups used to support customer billing.

Comment: ...which is to say: Defensive programming doesn't matter until it does, but when it matters, it *really* matters.

Comment: Yikes. Changed to `shlex.split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can pass the full command line as a string:

```
subprocess.call('whatever.exe {}'.format(v))
```

but it's not a very good idea because if some arguments contained in `v` have spaces in it you have to do the quoting manually (and as Charles reminded me for the 50th time it only works on Windows unless `shell=True` is set, which is another bad idea)

Another option would be using `shlex.split` and append to your already existing argument list (if executable has spaces in the path at least it is handled):

```
subprocess.call(['whatever.exe']+shlex.split(v))
```

but the best option is composing the list of arguments properly of course (as an actual `list`), and not passing a string to `subprocess` at all (safety, security & portability reasons to start with). If you're controlling what's in `v` you can change as a list, and if you don't, well, you're probably exposing your program to a possible attack or denial of service)

Comment: Is there a reason to concatenate strings via `'whatever.exe {}'.format(v)` instead of `'whatever.exe ' + v`?

Comment: Yes: you just forgot to append a space between `whatever.exe` and the rest of the arguments :). `str.format` is clearer.

Comment: +1 on the `shlex.split()`; -1 on the "pass the full command line as a string" (Windows is a different beast, but on UNIX that just won't work without `shell=True`), so right now I'm at =0.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will edit. OP is using windows (you already told me that but I tend to forget that :))

Comment: Reading in the platform from the `.exe` extension, or did they say it explicitly somewhere? (CLR binaries *are* executable on UNIX systems where `binfmt_misc` or an equivalent has been used to tell Mono to invoke them).

Comment: I meant "OP is probably using windows" and "I use windows all the time hence I forgot about the linux part :)". Yes `.exe` extension tipped me. In both cases, bad idea (I remember you pointed out that `shlex.split` wasn't so good either. Personally I prefer composing the list of args as a list. Most portable & secure way.